# MPMoviePlayer not showing controlls in iOS 8 for streaming url

Tags: ipad, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayer to stream video in **iOS 8**.Taping on player does not show controls in iPad.But its working in iOS 7.After playing in full screen,controls shows and working fine.The url contain .m3u8 file.I have tested with .mp4 url and its working fine in iOS 8.I think problem is with streaming url only.

Comment: Have you got any solution to the problem??

Comment: My MPMoviePlayer is not always displaying Duration of the Video. Some times it shows sometimes not.

Comment: Not yet.Apple may changed some property for streaming URLs.I think it's a problem from Apple side and lets wait for fix.

Comment: I guess the m3u8 file isn't detailed enough to get duration... can you post your m3u8 file?

Comment: ever figure out a solution to this? I'm having the same issue!